# Multiple values(optgroup with values) in select tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a select tag which is having multiple categories with values as option So when I select a value from the drop down I get same option in select.but my requirement is to have values with categories in select tag.

Actual when I select French 1 from select option

**French 1**

Expected

**French Languages-French 1**

HTML

```
<select id="lang"></select>
```

Jquery

```
    var data = [
    {
        name: "English Languages",
        values: ["English 1", "English 2", "English 3", "English 4"]
    },
    {
        name: "French Languages",
        values: ["French 1", "French 2", "French 3", "French 4"]
    },
    {
        name: "Spanish Languages",
        values: ["Spanish 1", "Spanish 2", "Spanish 3", "Spanish 4"]
    }
];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var category = data[i];
    var optgroup = $("<optgroup>").prop("label", category.name);
    for(var j = 0; j < category.values.length; j++)
        optgroup.append($("<option>").text(category.values[i]));

    $("#lang").append(optgroup);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wNjLm/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = [
    {
        name: "English Languages",
        values: ["English 1", "English 2", "English 3", "English 4"]
    },
    {
        name: "French Languages",
        values: ["French 1", "French 2", "French 3", "French 4"]
    },
    {
        name: "Spanish Languages",
        values: ["Spanish 1", "Spanish 2", "Spanish 3", "Spanish 4"]
    }
];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var category = data[i];
    var optgroup = $("<optgroup>").prop("label", category.name);
    for(var j = 0; j < category.values.length; j++)
        optgroup.append($("<option>").text(category.values[i]));

    $("#lang").append(optgroup);
}
function changeData() {
  var label = $('select :selected').parent().attr('label');
  var selectedLang = $('select option:selected').text();
  $('select option:selected').text(label + '-' + selectedLang);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="lang" onchange="changeData()"></select>
```

Comment: i am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: changeData is not defined on selecting in fiddle

Comment: thanx Saw Zin Min Tun

Comment: its not working with bootstrap select here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mfrup5bL/261/

Answer (score 0):

You can change 2nd for loop index i to j (category.values[j])

```js
var data = [
  {
   name: "English Languages",
   values: ["English 1", "English 2", "English 3", "English 4"]
  },
  {
   name: "French Languages",
   values: ["French 1", "French 2", "French 3", "French 4"]
  },
  {
   name: "Spanish Languages",
   values: ["Spanish 1", "Spanish 2", "Spanish 3", "Spanish 4"]
  }
 ];

 for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var category = data[i];
  var optgroup = $("<optgroup>").prop("label", category.name);
  for(var j = 0; j < category.values.length; j++)
   optgroup.append($("<option>").text(category.values[j]));

  $("#lang").append(optgroup);
 }
  
  function changeData() {
  var label = $('select :selected').parent().attr('label');
  var selectedLang = $('select option:selected').text();
  $('select option:selected').text(label + '-' + selectedLang);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="lang"  onchange="changeData()"></select>
```

Comment: i am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: changeData is not defined on selecting in fiddle